# Defining a custom 404 for non-WordPress parts of site

Tags: redirect, 404-error

I have a site with WordPress located in a directory under the root. The root directory contains the main files for the non-WordPress part of the site. Wordpress is included in all of these pages by inclusion of wp-load.php and this is working fine.

My question is about how best to handle 404 errors generated in this external part of the site. I'd like to have a single 404 page and ideally to use the WP 404 page for this purpose.

Is this possible and does anyone know how it could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the WordPress `index.php` as error handler in your `.htaccess` (if you are using Apache):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /wp/index.php
```

Make sure the path matches the path to the WordPress directory.